# Hide tab bar xcode for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a TabBar based app, where I have 4 tabs in 2nd tab I have a UICollectionView control to show images coming from a RSS feed.

When user click on any image it should Navigate to show in another UIViewController for more Details about that Image. I want to hide the TabBar in Detail Page. I tried many Ways but it not working.

Below is my code on selection in the `UICollectionView`:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailView *detail=[[DetailView alloc] init];
    detail.item= (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    [detail setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    [self.myCollectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I set `setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES` for detail page still the tab bar showing in detail page.

Should I have to do any thing else here.

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Do you have a navigation controller? Check out [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-how-to-hide-tab-bar-navigation-controller/) article.

Comment: yes am using storyboard and i have navigation controller... am checking the article

Comment: If so, then you're good to go with the solution provided in the linked articel! :-)

Comment: i checked the article but still no result.

Comment: i just checked that my customized tab is making issue here when i follow u r tutorial the code was working. if i add my customized tab bar it giving issue is there any solution along with customized tab i followed [this tutorail to customize my tab bar](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/)

Comment: I see, you've customized your tab bar by subclassing UITabBarController. That's something Apple discourages you to do in the first place! So it's hard to tell here what's going wrong with your subclassed UITabBarController class. Do you need only visual customization on your tab bar? If so, did you consider working with the appearance API?

Comment: Yes i want only show my images on each tab. So is there any other way for that? I mean Customizing the tab according to the need. what about appearance API. I don't know much about appearance API can please share some information with me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial answer was converted to a comment. Because of the shortness of it i think (barely more than a link to an external site)!

But, as you've elaborated in your last comment to me what you really need: if you want to change the appearance of your UITabBar, you don't necessarily need to subclass UITabBarController for this purpose. It depends on the extent of the customization you need but check out Apples "Appearance API" first. Here is a good article from Ray Wenderlich's site on [User Interface Customization in iOS5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) (applies also for iOS6, a sample project is included with the article).

[Here's](http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/) another good take on the Tab Bar customization via the Appearance API.

Comment: i will check this appearance api. but just check my requirement from this [Image link](http://stc.805225.com/design.png). Is it better to go with Images or just changing the color of tab. Please guide me as just recently started the iphone app development.

Comment: Ok, i see! Judging by the linked image, you'll probably need a custom Tab Bar! And what i mean is a custom Tab Bar implementation, not by subclassing UITabBarController or so. The problem is the tab bar item, which apparently is allowed to "stick out" beyond the Tab Bar! This can't be accomplished through the Appearance API solely i think! You should check out some custom Tab Bar implementations con [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar) maybe.

Comment: Thanks Nenad M. Your information taking me to correct direction am still working on my requirement. Really u r information i valuable.

Comment: Hi Mohammed! You're welcome! If it helped, you could vote my answer up! :-)

Comment: There is one more solution i found here [LINK](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html). It may help some one else.

Answer (score 2):

Your `DetailView` is view controller as your pushing it in `self.navigationController`.

Override the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` method of the `DetailView` ViewController, as your adding NavigationController as one of the view in TabBarController, you can directly access object `tabBarController` in the stack of viewcontrollers which belongs to `NavigationController`.

Please try following code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    // if you added bottom bar thr xib or thr code on DetailView VC, better if you remove it from DetailView xib
    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES]; 

    // this will hide the Tabbar  
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];

    // this will show the Tabbar  
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: i checked your code still its not working in my app. i would like to tell one thing here. i customized my tab bar with my own 4 images. may be this customization making any issue here.

Comment: you can create tabBarController object in your .h and mapped it in your TabbarController xib instead of `self.tabBarController`, do NSLog and verify self.tabBarController does has reference or not

Comment: after i remove my customization of tab bar the hiding is working. i followed [this](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/) tutorial to make my tab bar customized is there any other way.